# UK Standard Visitor Visa for Indonesian citizen (visa-national)

Tags: standard-visitor-visas, proof-of-funds, indonesian-citizens, proof-of-accommodation, evidence

Edited so that it is in line with forum:

I am a British citizen currently living in Bali, Indonesia. I live with my Indonesian boyfriend, where we both work. I plan on going back to the UK for up to 10 days around Easter time to visit my friends and family and we would like for my boyfriend to be able to come too. We have looked at the application process but we are slightly concerned as to whether his visa application will be successful or not.

Our main concern is the bank statements needed to prove that he has the funds to support the holiday to the UK. Unfortunately he does not have a bank account as he cannot register for a bank account in Bali (he doens't hold a resident card for Bali a he is originally from West Java, and without the resident card he cannot open an account), so his money is kept in my bank account. We live together so rent and bills are payed from that account. The only payment he makes on his own per se, is for his motorbike each month. Would it suffice to show my bank statements? I understand that this would in essence make me his sponsor for the trip (I understand it is possible for a third party - in this case me - to sponsor his holiday). It should be noted as well that I have only had a Balinese bank account for the last 5 months as prior to that I was waiting for my KITAS, so my statements would only go back that far.

Comment: In addition, you should read [the visa application form guidance](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/424265/VAF1-GUIDANCE-NOTES.pdf), the [guide to supporting documents](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/549692/Visitor_Supporting_Documents_Guide_-_English_version.pdf) and the [guidance on how the UK will evaluate your application](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/490874/Visitor_guidance_v4_0.pdf).

Comment: Thanks @GayotFow I will edit accordingly. Sorry, It was the first time I posted on this wonderfully helpful forum.

Comment: ping me after you edit so I can see if I can add something useful in an answer

Comment: @GayotFow I have edited it accordingly. Again, any help and advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Right, the premise looks weak and needs some bolstering; I'll think about how to say it. And remember that the joint bank statements have the extra added purpose of demonstrating a committed relationship.  It mitigates the chances of absconding.

Comment: Hi @GayotFow, I am now even more confused than before. Basically we both have stable jobs in Bali but I am British and we want to go visit my family and friends (we went to visit his family and friends in September in West Java, so it's my turn this time round). We have jobs to come back to, a dog to come back, a house to come back to. We have the funds to pay for the trip, but the funds are in my bank account. Is providing my bank statements, along with a letter saying that I will support his trip, suffice as the financial proof? We will provide the other necessary docs too.

Comment: Sorry, what's confusing?

Comment: @GayotFow I'm just confused as to whether or not providing my bank statements (that have both of our funds) is appropriate for this application, and whether I need to provide a affidavit of support? Sorry for all the questions, but I feel rather overwhelmed by this all and I do truly appreciated your response.

Comment: Right, it's best to come to the chat room and put some shape on your questions and then ask a new one.  http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/591/you-are-here

Comment: @GayotFow thanks but unfortunately I don't have a high enough reputation to write in the chat.

Comment: Rosie: your reputation is now sufficient for chat.

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of questions so I'll try to answer each one individually:

> 'you'll leave the UK at the end of your visit' - is a letter from his
>   employer stating that he is due to go back into work after our holiday
>   enough proof?

No. It isn't. People often extend leaves quit their jobs while on vacation, etc. So this letter is not that strong of evidence. Strong evidence would be family ties, a business that he has to run, property he has to manage, etc.

A letter *of employment* however, stating your partner's position, **how long he has been working there**, the amount of his salary does show proof of ties.

A letter from the office stating that he is due to get back to work would only work if the office was sponsoring or paying for part of his trip, in which case (in addition to the letter you mentioned) another would be required mentioning the kind of support provided.

> We don't want to book a flight before his visa is approved, just in case.

As well you shouldn't. In most visa applications, only a flight *booking* is required, but some consulates require a full reservation. You may want to check by calling the local office; and @GayotFow might be able to answer a bit more authoritatively on this point.

> 'you're able to support yourself and any dependents for the duration
>   of your trip' - I understand that this should be shown with bank
>   statements. We share our bank account here as he is not from Bali and
>   can therefore not open a bank account in Bali as he doesn't have a
>   Bali resident card(he can only open a bank account in West Java, where
>   he is from).
>
> So, can we show my bank statements?
>
> 'you're able to pay for your return or onward journey and any other
>   costs relating to your visit' - I suppose this relates to the bank
>   statement question above.

These two are related. Keep in mind that each applicant is judged on their own individual circumstances. In your case, effectively you are the sponsor for your partner on this trip - in that all the finances are in your name. I would consider drafting an affidavit of support mentioning your details, and your partner's and that you are willing to assume the costs of your partner's trip.

> Finally, should we provide a letter stating that we are travelling
>   together and that we will be visiting my family and that we are both
>   working in Bali (I have a KITAS) so we are obviously going to come
>   back and we can afford the trip?

This letter would not help your application, I would personally not include it as it cannot provide evidence sufficient to the nature and purpose of your trip. Just because you have KITAS doesn't mean your partner will be coming back.

> We plan on spending a couple of days in London so we can see my
>   brother and my friends and we will be staying with my brother, before
>   heading down south to stay with my family there.
>
> My parents have a house there and I use that address as my home
>   address, so would that suffice as proof as to where he is staying?

Ah here is something good. You can have your parents submit a letter stating that they are aware that you are arriving with your partner (along with his details), and that they agree to host you both at their residence (provide proof of residence such as a deed letter, utility payments in your parent's name, tax receipts, etc.) and additionally if they are able to - they may want to add that they are also willing to cover the expenses of your trip.

---

Now, given all the above I have to say your application is of high risk - as it is very easy for you and your partner to elope to the UK, get married and for him to be a de-facto immigrant.  There is of course, nothing wrong with you marrying whomever you choose its just that the type of visa and the kind of scrutiny given to those applications is different than just hey we are going for holiday together.

Comment: Per your comment about Gayot...  Gayot says one should NOT submit flight reservations as evidence. Doing so can actually hurt the applicant. So don't do it. Same thing goes for hotel bookings. In fact you shouldn't be making reservations in advance of a decision anyway.  Good luck @Rosie, hope you succeed.